# How to show a certain table and its child and parent tables on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I have a one query for oracle. I wrote it for fetching the Parent and Child tables of a certain table.

I need this query on Postgressql. In the below query it will just change the owner and table name, and the database will show you the Parent and Child tables for a specified table.

Is there a similar sql on postgres?

```
select 
      T1.R_OWNER           OWNER, 
      T2.TABLE_NAME        TABLENAME,
      T1.CONSTRAINT_NAME   CONSTRAINT_NAME,
      'CHILD' REFERENCE_TYPE
from SYS.DBA_CONSTRAINTS t1
LEFT JOIN SYS.DBA_CONSTRAINTS t2 ON T1.R_OWNER = T2.OWNER AND T1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = T2.constraint_name
WHERE T1.OWNER = 'GOLDSHOP'
AND T1.TABLE_NAME IN ('ARTUL')
AND T1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'

UNION ALL

select 
      T1.OWNER           OWNER, 
      T1.TABLE_NAME        TABLENAME,
      T1.CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_NAME,
      'PARENT' REFERENCE_TYPE
from SYS.DBA_CONSTRAINTS t1
LEFT JOIN SYS.DBA_CONSTRAINTS t2 ON T1.R_OWNER = T2.OWNER AND T1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = T2.constraint_name
WHERE T2.OWNER = 'GOLDSHOP'
AND T2.TABLE_NAME IN ('ARTUL')
```

Comment: You should query `information_schema.referential_constraints` and `information_schema.table_constraints` to get that information. That is better that querying the actual catalogs, and it will work on any standard confirming relational database

Comment: Yes, this tables show the information about constraints, but with this tables we are not able to find the child and parent tables of main table

Comment: All the information you need is in those views.